# Issue With Table Col 1

Tags: r, statistics

I have an issue with the table function. I'm obviously not using the correct function or not executing it correctly. It is combining the ContactCode Column with the Month of Dec and I need them separate. How do I specify the ContactCode is its own column when using the Table function?

```
Map = HeatMapCC[,c('ContactCode','Month')]
Map = table(Map$ContactCode,Map$Month)
```

The Output

```
      Dec Jan
  101 219 315
  103  37  47
  104  69  72
  110  26  60
  112  41  24
  113  18  28
```

Desired OutPut

```
  ContactCodes    Dec Jan
  101             219 315
  103             37  47
  104             69  72
  110             26  60
  112             41  24
  113             18  28

> str(Map)
 'table' int [1:26, 1:2] 219 37 69 26 41 18 106 2 26 19 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:26] "101" "103" "104" "110" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "Dec" "Jan"
```

Comment: Am I seeing things or are your output and desired output essentially identical?

Comment: @Thomas, its setting the `ContactCodes` as the `rownames`

Comment: The ContactCodes data is being grouped into the Dec column. I need them separated.

Comment: its not being "grouped in", it just may appear that way when printing to screen.  Have a look at a `rownames(Map)` and `Map[, "Dec"]`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta So it is.

Answer (score 1):

If your output is called `Map` do the following:

```
Map <- cbind(ContactCode=rownames(Map), Map)
```

---

As Hong pointed out, if the rownames are not all numeric, you might get unwanted coerced values.  You can use `data.frame` in place of `cbind` for these situations.  ie:

```
Map <- data.frame(ContactCode=rownames(Map), Map)
```

---

Note, in either case, if you don't like the look of the rownames still present after adding them as a column, you can get rid of them:

```
rownames(Map) <- NULL
Map
  ContactCode Dec Jan
1         101 219 315
2         103  37  47
3         104  69  72
4         110  26  60
5         112  41  24
6         113  18  28
```

Comment: yes that is true.  In which case, data.frame will do.  I will update the answer, thanks Hong

Comment: There's actually another problem: `data.frame` on a table will convert it to a long format (basically what `expand.grid` would give you). So you also need to `unclass` it first.